# Rails - Synchronise button clicks among tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have a view with bootstrap-tabs. The tabs are generated dynamically.

```
<%= form_with(:id => 'my-form', model: [:admin, @island], local: true) do |form| %>
  <div class="tab-content bg-light" id="tabs-from-locales-content">

    <%= available_locales.each_with_index do |locale, i| %>
      <div
      class="tab-pane fade <%= 'show active' if i == 0 %>"
      id="<%= locale.downcase %>"
      role="tabpanel"
      aria-labelledby="<%= locale.downcase %>-tab">
        <%= render partial: 'island_form', locals: {counter: i, locale: locale, f: form} %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

  </div>

...
...
```

A tab represents each available localization of the app.
The model of the form contains two nested attributes. These attributes have `1 to many` relationship with the model. So the user can add multiple of these from the form. Their fields can be generated dynamically:

(For simplicity I include in the question only one. This is a part of `_island_form.html.erb` partial.)

```
<div class="form-group ports-div">
  <%= f.label :port %> </br>
  <%= f.fields_for :ports do |builder| %>

    <%= render 'port_fields', f: builder %>

  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_fields t('form.add_port'), f, :ports %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :airport %> </br>
  <%= f.fields_for :airports do |builder| %>

    <%= render 'airport_fields', f: builder %>

  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_fields t('form.add_airport'), f, :airports %>
</div>
```

And the `port_fields` partial:

```
<fieldset>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
  <%= link_to t('form.remove'), '#', class: 'remove_fields' %>
</fieldset>
```

The `link_to_add_fields` helper method:

```
  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    # Builds an instance of the association record.
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    # Grabbing ruby's object id.
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + '_fields', f: builder)
    end
    link_to(name, '#', class: 'add_fields', data: { id: id, fields: fields.gsub('\n', '') })
  end
```

What I want to achieve is to synchronize the addition and removal of these fields among the available tabs. So when the user clicks `Add field` on the first tab all the other tabs will follow this action. Same for field removal.

My relevant `js` file for the `Add` button looks like this. I have tried many combinations between the `trigger`, `triggerHandler` and `stopPropagation`, although most of the times I am getting `StackOverflow exception` and the fields are added only to the tab that I clicked the `add` button.

(Since I pass a class (`.add_fields`) in the `selector` isn't that supposed to be attached to all the elements with class `.add_fields`?)

```
form.on('click', '.add_fields', function (event, param) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    var time = new Date().getTime();
    var regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g');
    $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time));

    $('.tab-pane').each(function (index) {

        $('.add_fields').trigger("click", ["custom_click"]);
        console.log('Tab - ' + index);
    })
});
```

**EDIT**

I am getting somewhere with that code:

```
    $('.ports-div').each(function (index) {

        $(this).find('.add_fields').each(function () {
            this.click();
        })
    });
```

Although, at all the tabs, instead of 1 field 6 fields are added. I added the `ports-div` to the div that wraps all the related elements.

Answer (score 1):

**Complete rewrite...**

The problem as you have seen is to be that your *click* event handler is triggering a click on all tab-panes, including the one you are handling currently. You are also not just clicking the a single item in the loop, but all that match '.add_fields'. This then leads to the click being handled again, recursively.

To prevent this, I suggest calling a function to add your fields directly, rather than triggering a click. If triggering a click is just easiest in your situation, consider the following example that does roughly what you want without the recursive error.

https://jsfiddle.net/3ftf0j8e/1/

**Dummy HTML**

```
<a class="add_fields" id='1'>link 1</a>    
<a class="add_fields" id='2'>link 2</a>    
<a class="add_fields" id='3'>link 3</a>    
<a class="add_fields" id='4'>link 4</a>
```

**Sample Javascript**

```
$(document).on('click', '.add_fields', function (event, param) {
    event.preventDefault();


    var clicked_id = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log('clicked id:' + clicked_id);

    $(this).addClass('done');
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    // Just click items that have not been clicked
    var els = $('.add_fields').not('.clicked');
    console.log(els);    
    els.trigger("click");

    setTimeout(function(){
      if($('.add_fields').length == $('.add_fields.done').length)
        $('.add_fields').removeClass('clicked');
    })

});
```

**CSS**

```
a.clicked {
  background-color: yellow;
}

a.done {
  color: red;
}
```

As you can see now, each fires just once. The setTimeout at the end allows the DOM to update before clearing the *clicked* classes.

Comment: It doesn't work, it only adds the field in the current tab

Comment: I just noticed an error. I will update in one minute. Sorry.

Comment: It doesn't, `console.log(clicked_id)` is `undefined` by the way.

Comment: Also, `.add_fields` is an link tag so i guess i should use `.click` to trigger it

Comment: With your code no matter in which tab i press the button, all fields are added to the first tab and I get `Stack Overflow` error

Comment: I've completely rewritten my answer and provided a Fiddle to show how it works. I hope you can adapt for your more complex application.

Comment: It actually works. The problem is that I have two nested objects in the form (ports and airports) that operate in the same way. So if I click `Add Field` for the ports, an airport field is added as well.

Comment: It will be a matter of adjusting the CSS selectors on the line `var els = $('.add_fields').not('.clicked');` to include only the Add Field button you want. Either add an additional class to the link, to select something like `.add_fields.port` or `.add_fields.airport`, or through a form or fieldset. At this point it is a matter of standard JQuery.

Comment: I managed to fix that by doing `var elementClass = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1]; var els = $('.add_fields.' + elementClass).not('.clicked');`. There is another problem... Clicking the first tab, will add 1 field to the second tab but 2 on the 3rd tab. If I click `Add` on the 3rd tab it adds 2 on the 1st and 1 in the 2nd. Weird behavior, any idea what it might be?

Comment: Without seeing the code it is hard to say. You should inspect the markup produced in your browser to ensure all the links and forms have the classes you expect. Also, I think you can use `$(this)[0].classList[1]` to get at the actual class names without having to manipulate attribute strings. Or use something like `data-add-type="port"` on the element to clearly mark the usage of the element. It sounds like you are making progress. Good luck!

Comment: It's still far from a good solution. For example, if I click `Add` on the first tab then go click `Add` on the 3rd tab it will only update the 3rd tab, since the other tabs will have `clicked` class. There are problems like that plus the aforementioned one. Definitely, your solution can get me started from somewhere though. I will try to update my question with a simpler example of the case.

Comment: The other tabs should not retain the clicked class after the initial click has completed. There is an error in your code, or the setTimeout in my example is not working. Do you have any errors in your javascript console?

Comment: So, I modified your code as such [link](https://jsfiddle.net/wt2gqm6c/1/) .Although you can see [here](https://imgur.com/a/FTW3s) that the last tab's button is triggered twice (see the blue 2 at the bottom right of the screenshot). This example is after clicking `Add` on the first tab. If I click the last tab, the middle one is triggered twice. I spent a lot of time but I still can't troubleshoot that...